# Loop through Range of sheets

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops, range

I am trying to loop through a range of sheets. However, I get an error when selecting the sheets from a range on a sheet.

```
Sub Calc_sheets()

Dim sheetnames As Variant
sheets("Calc_sheets").Select
'sheetnames = Worksheets("Calc_sheets").Range("a2:a4").Value # returns an error in row "Sheet = sheetnames(k)"

sheetnames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2") # works fine

For k = 0 To Application.CountA(sheetnames) - 1

        Sheet = sheetnames(k)
        sheets(Sheet).Select
        ActiveSheet.Calculate
Next k

End Sub
```

Do you know how to solve this?

Best,

Comment: Untested, but I think you just need to say, `Set sheetnames = Worksheets...`

Comment: Not a good idea to use `.Select` and `ActiveSheet.` anyway. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: What's is your array base?  If the array is `sheetnames(1)="Sheet1": sheetnames(2)="Sheet2"` then `sheetnames(0)` will return an error.  Use `Lbound` and `Ubound` to check

Answer (score 3):

Use Lbound and Ubound to loop through the array.

Declare the sht as a worksheet and Set the sheet.  Then avoid the use of select and activate.

```
Sub Calc_sheets()

Dim sheetnames As Variant
Dim sht as Worksheet


sheetnames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

For k = LBound(sheetnames) to Ubound(sheetnames)

        Set Sht = worksheets(sheetnames(k))
        sht.Calculate
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: `shet` ? not `sht ? you were trying to type so fast ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado The purpose of this macro is calculation.  It's all about getting shet done.

Comment: Great. How can I pull the sheetnames form a Range from a sheet?

Comment: Sheetnames = worksheets ("sheet3").range("A1:A4").value @AlexKlindt

Comment: This returns Runtime error 9 for me -  in line `Set sht = Worksheets(sheetnames(k))`

Comment: I removed the "note" but that would not have caused the error.  That error is because you have misspelled the sheet names.  Double check the sheet names and that the names do not have spaces or other unprintable characters not accounted for in your strings. @AlexKlindt

Answer (score 3):

you have to use `Set`

```
Dim Sheet AS Worksheet
Set Sheet = sheetnames(k)
```

but you can shorten it down to

```
Sub Calc_sheets()
    Dim sheetnames As Variant
    sheetnames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    Dim Sheet As Variant
    For Each Sheet In sheetnames
        Sheets(Sheet).Calculate
    Next
End Sub
```

or even shorter:

```
Sub Calc_sheets()
    Dim Sheet As Variant
    For Each Sheet In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
        Sheets(Sheet).Calculate
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CalcSheets()

    Dim k           As Long
    Dim sheetnames  As Variant

    sheetnames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")

    For k = 0 To Application.CountA(sheetnames) - 1
        Sheets(sheetnames(k)).Calculate
    Next k    
End Sub
```

In general, `Select` and `ActiveSheet` should be avoided and if you are using `.Calculate` explicitly something should be quite wrong in the whole worksheet design.